# @neo4j/graphql and @auth directive usage for CRUD operations

Tags: neo4j, graphql, nestjs, neo4j-graphql-js

I'm using `@neo4j/graphql` library to define my graphql API interface. I've got my Todo model and I would like anyone to read it, but I'd like only admin role to be able to edit it. I'm using NestJS as backend. Type definition is as follows:

```js
// type-defs.ts
export typeDefs = gql(`
type Todo {
    id: ID! @id
    owner: String!
    title: String
  }

  extend type Todo
    @auth(
      rules: [
        { operations: [READ], allowUnauthenticated: true }
        { operations: [CREATE, DELETE, UPDATE], allow: { roles: ["ADMIN"] } }
      ]
    )
`);


// gql.module.ts

const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({
  typeDefs,
  driver,
  plugins: {
    auth: new Neo4jGraphQLAuthJWKSPlugin({
      jwksEndpoint: `https://cognito-idp.${process.env.COGNITO_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}`,
    }),
  },
});

@Module({
  providers: [],
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      useFactory: async () => {
        const schema = await neoSchema.getSchema();
        await neoSchema.assertIndexesAndConstraints({
          options: { create: true },
        });
        return {
          playground: true,
          schema,
          // // change property `cognito:groups` to `roles` in the jwt.payload passed to Neo4jGraphQLAuthJWKSPlugin
          context: authContextFunction,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class GqlModule {}
```

I'd expect all users to be able to read it, but only logged in and admins to be able to perform any CUD operation.
If I run this without token, I get `Unauthenticated` error, which is perfect.
However, when I use token generated by hand, it allows me to create content. Here is the token passed to the auth plugin:

```json
 {
  sub: '10',
  email: 'bob@example.com',
  iat: 1562061850,
  exp: 1562065450,
  roles: [ 'B' ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your Schema is how it used the property
[allow](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/auth/authorization/allow/)
that should be used to perform a match with a property in a Node,
to perform a check using the JWT field roles, then you should use the property [roles](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/auth/authorization/roles/).

Using your example:

```
type Todo {
  id: ID! @id
  owner: String!
  title: String
}

extend type Todo @auth(
  rules: [
    { operations: [READ], allowUnauthenticated: true }
    { operations: [CREATE, DELETE, UPDATE], roles: ["ADMIN"] }
  ]
)
```

Comment: oh god, you're absolutely right, thank you!